# Непонятное поведение ресурса картинки в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

Ресурс картинки при повторном использовании в приложении пропадает с первого места. 
Как это можно объяснить и исправить?

Подробности:
Регистрирую ресурс в xaml главного окна

```
   <Window.Resources>        
        <Image x:Key="CloseImg" Source="Images/1467501383_Delete.png"></Image>
        ...
   </Window.Resources>
```

В нем же его и использую:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="139">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" ></RowDefinition>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Width="16" Height="16" Name="ToolsPanelClose" Grid.Column="1"   Content="{StaticResource CloseImg}" Click="ToolsPanelClose_Click"></Button>
                        <TextBlock Padding="2" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  >Tools</TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
```

Но когда я пытаюсь его использовать во втором месте в программе, то он визуально не отображается в первом месте

```
TabControl WebPagesTabs;    
WebPagesTabs.Items.Add(TabItemFactory("Newbtn"));

private TabItem TabItemFactory(string tabType)
        {

            switch (tabType)
            {  
                case "Newbtn":                    
                    {
                        TabItem htab = new TabItem();
                        StackPanel hStackPanel = new StackPanel();
                        hStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                        TextBlock hTextBlock = new TextBlock(new Run("New"));
                        Button hCloseBtn = new Button();
                        hCloseBtn.Width = 24;
                        hCloseBtn.Height = 24;
                        hCloseBtn.Content = this.Resources["CloseImg"];
                        hStackPanel.Children.Add(hTextBlock);
                        htab.Name = "Newbtn";
                        htab.Header = hStackPanel;
                        return htab;

                    }
           default:return null;
           }
      }
```

[image: Картинка с UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте атрибут `x:Shared`.

```
<Image x:Key="CloseImg" x:Shared="False" Source="Images/1467501383_Delete.png" />
```